# I want to add roles to my friends on join but the on_member_join() event is not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that will give specific users(my friends) the default role(member) this is my code but it doesn't seem to work nor any errors are shown:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="892295184790990898")
    if member.id == 857153014447079424:
        await client.add_roles(member, role)
        print("ADDED")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you try the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member = None):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "892295184790990898")
    if member.id == 857153014447079424:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print("Added")
```

Use `member.add_roles(role)` instead. Also, if you're checking if anyone who joins is your friend or a user you want to have the role, I recommend storing all of your friends ID's in a list and doing this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member = None):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "892295184790990898")
    friends_ids = [] # add your id's here. Make sure that they are integers and not strings.
    if member.id in friends_ids:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print("Added")
```

Also for good practice, I recommend making your arguments "Typesafe". Typesafe is when an argument to a function, or anything else can only be a specific data type. To do this in python, it would be `def func(x: int)`
This would make it so that the only data type allowed for the argument `x` is an integer. Use this for discord members as I have above. You don't have to, and it is not necessary, but it will help.

The top code snippet is a modified version of a snipper from my own discord bot. Though I have my code in a cog, you might find it useful incase you would like another example:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member = None):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = 'ROLE NAME HERE')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await self.bot.get_channel(MY CHANNEL ID HERE).send(f"MY MESSAGE HERE")
```

Comment: None of them are working.

Comment: Its possible that you dont have the correct intents. Check your discord dev portal > applications > and make sure your bot has everything that you need selected

Comment: it has everything, it is admin and the role is above the role that i want to give, it is able to give role to any person if i run #welcome @user but it won't even print anything on `on_member_join`

Comment: Then I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `member.server.roles`, which doesn't return anything because the `member` object doesn't have a `server` attribute. Use `member.guild.roles` instead.

Comment: I used that already doesn't works.

Comment: Did you try using `await member.add_roles(role)` instead of `await elient.add_roles(member, role)`

Comment: yes i tried it also didn't work